# Why is this not creating a multi-select box in a Rails form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

The code is straight forward.

```
<%= f.select(:categories, options_for_select(@categories), {:multiple => true, :size => 10}) %><br />
```

This is creating a single select box. Not one where multiple ones can be selected. Rails 3.1.3.

Comment: This question will solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826407/rails-3-multiple-select-with-has-many-through-associations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

:multiple is a html_option

```
<%= f.select(:categories, options_for_select(@categories), {}, {:multiple => true, :size => 10}) %><br />
```