# How to update a many to many relationship with select_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, many-to-many, html-select, multi-select

Say I have a many-to-many relationship defined as follows:

In my user model :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :userName (...) 
 has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
end
```

In my group model :

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :groupName (...)
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

I added to my users controller in update and create:

```
@user.group_ids = Group.find(params[:group_ids]) if params[:group_ids]
```

The user form contains a multiselect list to choose the groups for each user (among other criteria that actually work):

```
<%= select_tag("group_ids[]", options_for_select(Group.find(:all).collect { |gro| [gro.groupName, gro.id] }, @user.groups.collect { |gro| gro.id}), {:multiple=>true, :size=>15}) %>
```

When I create or update a user, everything looks to work fine, but whatever the choice I make in the picklist, it adds to the user the wrong group (always the group with id=1).
I tried with `has_many_through` and migrated the database but had the issue too.

Do you know how to make the assignment happen ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the select tag, you can use the f.select form helper detailed in: [Rails 3: Multiple Select with has_many through associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826407/rails-3-multiple-select-with-has-many-through-associations)

Also, there are two-sided multi select that work perfectly as stated in: [two sided multi select that works with Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202929/two-sided-multi-select-that-works-with-rails-3)

I recommend the one from http://loudev.com/, you just need to use:

```
<%= f.select(:country, "country_id", Country.all.collect {|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }, {:include_blank => false}, {:class => "multiselect", :multiple => "multiple"}) %>
```

And add the following Javascript to your view:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
     $('.multiselect').multiSelect(); 
});
</script>
```