# How can I create a has_many through record using simple form ? I

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

My Category model :

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :item_categoryships
    has_many :items, :through => :item_categoryships
end
```

My Item model :

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :item_categoryships
    has_many :categories, class_name: 'ItemCategoryship', foreign_key: 'category_id', :through => :item_categoryships

end
```

My ItemCategoryship model:

```
class ItemCategoryship < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :item
    belongs_to :category
end
```

And in views/items/edit.html.erb, I wrote simple form code like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@item) do |f| %>
    <%= f.association :categories, collection: @categories, as: :check_boxes %>
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

The @categories above, I wrote this in controller:

```
@categories = current_user.categories
```

But I hit a problem, they can't save to database!!

I couldn't find out what the problem was. Please help me.... 
Thanks you all.

Comment: can you access `category.items` in the rails console?

Comment: Sorry....If that needs a controller to handle create action and desrtoy action? I only have created one minimal Rails website, I can't get a idea how can I handle check_boxes....

Comment: What relationship between these two models are you trying to create. Are you trying to assign an item to a category (i.e. one category per item)? A check box would not be the way to achieve this, but before you tackle that problem, you may need to work on the associations in the models themselves.

Comment: I want one item can have many categories...

Comment: then maybe you don't need `has_many :through` - `Category` should use the `belongs_to` association. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the view, this SO answer should help:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9917006/2463468

You may first need to make sure your associations make sense. Perhaps you only need a `has_many` on `Items` and `belongs_to` on `Category`.

You might be able to do without `ItemCategoryship`.