# Rails4 - Displaying items in the orders form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, select2-rails

I want the user to search through existing items from the items table in the orders form, it works for clients but not for items, it gives an error: **Association :item not found**

## Models

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :client

    has_many :order_items
    has_many :items, :through => :order_items
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :order_items
    has_many :orders, :through => :order_items
end

class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :item
    belongs_to :order
end
```

## Migration

```
class CreateOrderItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :order_items do |t|
        t.integer :item_id
        t.integer :order_id
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index   :order_items, [:item_id, :order_id]
  end
end
```

## View

```
<%= simple_form_for(@order) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
    <%= f.association :client, collection: Client.all, label_method: :name, value_method: :id, prompt: "Choose a Client", input_html: { id: 'client-select2' } %>
    <%= f.association :item, collection: Item.all, label_method: :name, value_method: :id, prompt: "Choose an item", input_html: { id: 'client-select2' }  %>
<%= f.input :memo, label: 'Comments' %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

## Controller

```
 def new
    @order = Order.new
  end

  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    @order.user_id = current_user.id
    @order.status = TRUE
  end
  def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(:code, :client_id, :user_id, :memo, :status,    items_attributes: [:id, :name, :price, :quantity, :status, :_destroy])
  end
```

## Answer

In the form use instead:
using rails-select2 gem

```
<%= f.association :items, collection: Item.all, label_method: :name, value_method: :id, prompt: "Choose an item", input_html: { id: 'item-select2' } %>
```

or without select2

```
<%= f.select :item_ids, Item.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, {}, multiple: true %>
```

Thanks to JKen13579

Comment: Why are you adding `has_many :order_items` and `has_many :items, :through => :order_items`? you should only add the second on AFAIK.

Comment: Also `belongs_to :user` with `belongs_to :client` looks weird, isn't a user actually a client?

Comment: I was referring to: [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) where they have the has_many, so I thought I would need it as well

Comment: well the users are the employees who are creating the orders for clients. the clients do not touch the system.

Comment: Aha I see, everything is fine regarding association logic then :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that you're receiving the error for `item` but not for `client` is because there is one `client` associated to an order, but more than one `item` associated to an order. It's saying `:item not found` because you should be using `:items` (note the plural).

To allow multi-select for your `order`'s `items`, replace your `f.association item` line with:

```
<%= f.select :item_ids, Item.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, {}, multiple: true %>
```

And then in your controller, be sure to permit `item_ids`. In addition, you don't need `item_attributes`, because you're not using `accepted_nested_attributes_for :items`.

```
def order_params
  params.require(:order).permit(:code, :client_id, :user_id, :memo, :status, item_ids: [])
end
```

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9917006/2856441) for more information about `has_many` `:through` multi-select.

Comment: `:items` worked, no errors are showing but after I submit the form while items selected, the table `:order_items` still shows as empty

Comment: Ah yes you're using strong parameters. It's it in [the SO answer I posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9917006/2856441), but I added it to my answer. Hopefully that solves it for you.

Comment: Wonderful that worked.
    `<%= f.association :items, collection: Item.all, label_method: :name, value_method: :id, prompt: "Choose an item", input_html: { id: 'item-select2' } %>`
Is what I used instead for multiselect with search (rails-select2 gem)