# Rails 5.1.4 - How do I create records from multi-select with a has_many :through relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multi-select, has-many-through

I got some problems with saving records from a `has_many :through` association. I must have missed something important.

First things first:

- Rails version: 5.1.4
- Ruby version: 2.4.2

I got these three models:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :events_timeslots
  has_many :timeslots, through: :events_timeslots
end

class Timeslot < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :events_timeslots
  has_many :events, through: :events_timeslots
end

class EventsTimeslot < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :timeslot
end
```

According to this, every event has many timeslots and every timeslot has many events.

I want a multi select in my view:

```
<%= form_with(model: event, local: true) do |form| %>
  ...
  <% fields_for :events_timeslots do |events_timeslots| %>
    <%= events_timeslots.label :timeslots %>
    <%= events_timeslots.select(:timeslots, @timeslots.collect {|t| [t.name, t.id]}, {}, {multiple: true}) %>
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Is this the right approach to select multiple timeslots while creating a new event? The timeslots already exist at this time but when the event gets saved, it should also create the associated records in the `events_timeslots` table.

I also permit the `timeslots` attribute in strong parameters:

```
params.require(:event).permit(:date, timeslots: [])
```

Is there a magic Rails-Way to use the "scaffolded" controller actions to create the new event as well as the associated records in EventsTimeslot model? Related to this question I found [an answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9917006/5529860), however I wasn't able to get it to work!

Maybe I missed a very stupid little thing, but anyways thanks for the help.

---

**Edit**

The (messed up) `events_timeslots` table in `schema.rb`:

```
create_table "events_timeslots", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.bigint "events_id"
  t.bigint "timeslots_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.index ["events_id"], name: "index_events_timeslots_on_events_id"
  t.index ["timeslots_id"], name: "index_events_timeslots_on_timeslots_id"   
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your foreign keys are the standard: `event_id` and `timeslot_id`...

Then perhaps try swapping `timeslots` with `timeslot_ids` in the `permit` method:

`params.require(:event).permit(:date, timeslot_ids: [])`

Then, rather than setting the attributes of the join table in a nested form, just update the `timeslot_ids` on the `@event`:

```
<%= form_with(model: event, local: true) do |form| %>

    <%= form.select(:timeslot_ids, Timeslot.all.collect {|t| [t.name, t.id]}, {}, {multiple: true}) %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: "Assuming your foreign keys are the standard" - turned out they weren't! I named them `events_id` and `timeslots_id` by mistake. Now it's perfectly working with `timeslot_ids` and the adjusted form. Thank you for the important hint to check the foreign key names! :)

Answer (score 2):

`fields_for` is for when you are creating nested records with `accepts_nested_attributes`.

Its not needed when you are simply associating items:

```
<%= form_with(model: event, local: true) do |form| %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:timeslot_ids, Timeslot.all, :id, :name, multiple: true) %>
<% end %>
```

ActiveRecord creates a `_ids` setter method for has_many associations that takes an array of ids. This works hand in hand with the [form helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html).

To whitelist an array param you need to pass it as a keyword to permit:

```
params.require(:event).permit(:foo, :bar, timeslot_ids: [])
```

Using `[]` permits any scalar value.

Comment: Hi, this was very helpful, but it should be `...:name, {}, multiple: true)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you’re looking for “autosave”, check here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html